# Is there anyway to replace something in the HttpPostedFileWrapper filename in all of my project in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have many actions which are used HttpPostedFileWrapper, I want to change the space " " to dash "-" in all of the filenames before call the **HttpPostedFileWrapper.filename**,
 I can do it one by one in all of my actions but they are many,
is there any way to change that on somewhere else? in onActionExecuting in filters for example,

Note that override is not a good solution because I have to change the name of input type in all actions again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I was in the wrong way because **HttpPostedFileWrapper.filename** is **readonly** and can not change it!